# Are there iOS devices that can monitor iBeacons but not range them?

Tags: ios7, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

Or asked another way will

```
[CLLocationManager isMonitoringAvailableForClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]]
```

and

```
[CLLocationManager isRangingAvailable]
```

ever return different values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer:  No, there are not any iOS devices that can monitor iBeacons but not range them.  Both methods will return the same value if isMonitoringAvailableForClass is given a CLBeaconRegion instance.

The reason the API looks this way is because the isMonitoringAvailableForClass method can be called with classes other than a CLBeaconRegion class.  CLCircularRegion is used for monitoring geofence regions.  The method might return NO when passed CLBeaconRegion on a device without LE Bluetooth, and return YES when passed a CLCircularRegion on the same device.

Comment: This is absolutely correct. For 4S +  devices - beacon monitoring and ranging both are available. You can still use CLRegion class if you do not want to deal with CLBeaconRegion. Otherwise you should use the new CLBeaconRegion and CLCircularRegion classes

Comment: Thanks, it just seems odd to me that there is a separate method for checking for ranging. I still use the respective check with each use case in case this isn't true in the future.

Comment: Understood.  But think about it from an API developer's perspective. Wouldn't it be a little clunky to ask a user to call [CLLocationManager isMonitoringAvailableForClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]] to see if ranging is available?  For all I know, [CLLocationManager isRangingAvailable] is just a wrapper around the above to make the API look cleaner.  Admittedly, this is just conjecture.

Comment: Wrote this small sample code to get started with iBeacons - hope it helps Hi Guys,
I wrote this small code to quickly get started with iBeacons - hope it helps :
https://github.com/manishnath/iBeaconCenter

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is one case when `[CLLocationManager isMonitoringAvailableForClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]]` will return `NO` and [CLLocationManager isRangingAvailable] will return `YES`.

If Background App Refresh is turned off `[CLLocationManager isMonitoringAvailableForClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]]` should return `NO`.

In Apple's *Location and Maps Programming Guide* under the "Determining the Availability of Region Monitoring" section:

> Before attempting to monitor any regions, your app should check
>   whether region monitoring is supported on the current device. Here are
>   some reasons why region monitoring might not be available:
>
> - The device doesn’t have the necessary hardware to support region monitoring.
> - The user denied the app the authorization to use region monitoring.
> - The user disabled location services in the Settings app.
> - **The user disabled Background App Refresh in the Settings app, either for the device or for your app.**
> - The device is in Airplane mode and can’t power up the necessary hardware.

(I've bolded the fourth bullet point, because it's the case I'm talking about.)

Ranging is, however, only a foreground activity so Background App Refresh settings aren't important.

In this one case region monitoring will not be available, but ranging will be available.

**Note:** Currently, when Background App Refresh is turned `[[CLLocationManager isMonitoringAvailableForClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]]` returns `YES`, but when you start monitoring you'll never get notification and if you call `requestStateForRegion:` then `locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager monitoringDidFailForRegion:(CLRegion *)region withError:(NSError *)error` will be called on the CLLocationManager's delegate.
The error message will be "The operation couldn't be completed." with an error code of 4, which translates via `CLError.h` to `kCLErrorRegionMonitoringDenied`.

I hope Apple will fix the false positive in `[[CLLocationManager isMonitoringAvailableForClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]]` in one the next few updates.